# How can I make multi line tableview headers in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have question about multiline header in tableview. I already tried `lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping` and `numberOfLines = 0` and I also set too

`tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
 tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 44`

But these solutions could not help me. How can I make multiline header for my tableview?

Here my header view code:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        if section == 0 { 
            let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 100))
            // code for adding centered title
            headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 225/255.0, green: 225/255.0, blue: 225/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 8, width: tableView.bounds.size.width - 120, height: 28))
            headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            headerLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            headerLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            headerLabel.text = headerTitleForSecZero
            headerLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
            headerLabel.textAlignment = .left
            headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)

            button.frame = CGRect(x:headerView.frame.size.width - 85, y:8, width:70, height:28)
            button.setTitle(buttonLabel,for: .normal)
            button.tag = 1
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleExpandCloseForAlim(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            adresDegistirmeButonu.frame = CGRect(x:headerView.frame.size.width - 100, y:8, width:90, height:28)

            headerView.addSubview(adresDegistirmeButonu)
            headerView.addSubview(button)
            return headerView
        }else{
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using numberOfLines will only work if you're using a text header rather than a headerView.  I'd use AutoLayout constraints to build your header view, relying on a label having it's own intrinsic height for autolayout that will increase the height of the view if extra lines are required (as long as numberOfLines = 0).

Comment: @ArashEtemad I already tried that solution but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, building the header view with AutoLayout constraints that allow the text label to grow should give you the flexibility you're looking for.  The example below just used a dummy array of mutli-line text to populate the header views.  It also sets the footers to not show as empty footers can confuse the layout.

```
class MyVC1: UIViewController {
   var tableView: UITableView!
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      addTableView()
   }

   func addTableView() {
      tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
      tableView.delegate = self
      tableView.dataSource = self
      view.addSubview(tableView)
      tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
      tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
      tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
      tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
      tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
   }
}

extension MyVC1: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      5
   }

   func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      3
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
      cell.textLabel?.text = "Section: \(indexPath.section), Row: \(indexPath.row)"
      return cell
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
  //set up dummy header text
      var text = [String]()
      text.append( "One Line")
      text.append("""
      Three Lines
      Three Lines
      Three Lines
      """)
      text.append("""
      Two Lines
      Two Lines
      """)


      let header = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 100))
      let label = UILabel()
      label.numberOfLines = 0
      let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
      button.setTitle("Press Me", for: .normal)
      button.setTitleColor(.purple, for: .normal)
      button.backgroundColor = .lightGray
      header.addSubview(label)
      header.addSubview(button)
      label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
         label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.topAnchor, constant: 10),
         label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
         label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
         button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.centerYAnchor),
         button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
         button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
         label.trailingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: button.leadingAnchor, constant: -50)
      ])
      label.text = text[section]
      return header
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
      nil
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
      0
   }
}
```